# Nginx mp4 hotlink protection doesnt work

Tags: nginx

I am trying to block hotlinking of my mp4 with nginx "valid_referers" :

```
valid_referers none blocked mysite.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return   403;
            }
```

But it doesnt work at all, the mp4 still display on the websites who are stealing the video and if I put some random domain instead of "mysite.com" the video still work.

If it can help, this is what my server conf file look like :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name dl.mysite.com;
    root /home/videos;

    index index.php index.html;

    autoindex off; 

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    # streaming
    location ~ \.mp4$ {

        valid_referers none blocked mysite.com;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return   403;
        }

        gzip off;
        gzip_static off;

        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size 1M;
        mp4_max_buffer_size 300M;
    }

    location ~ .flv$ {
        flv;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }


    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/lobby(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in past. I thought it was not working, but actually, it was working. Just make sure you are not allowing anyone except you.

Sometimes leechers try null or empty referrers to bypass this and there is no possible solution to this. One possible solution I can suggest to block the resource directory. See https://www.atulhost.com/hotlink-protection-nginx this man explained everything in a simple way.